# JQuery - Change attr based on element innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, attr

I'm trying to add schema markup to products across our site, but I want the attr of the div element to change based on what the text is for the innerHTML

HTML:

```
<div class="badgeIds" itemtype="https://schema.org/ItemAvailability" itemprop="availability">
   Online Only
</div>
```

Here is what I wrote for the Javascript. Is my logic flawed?

```
var avail = document.find("div.badgeIds");

if (avail.html().trim() == "Preorder") {
      avail.attr("itemprop", "availability:Preorder");
} elseif (avail.html().trim() == "Online Only") {
      avail.attr("itemprop", "availability:OnlineOnly");
} elseif (avail.html().trim() == "Available In Store Only") {
      avail.attr("itemprop", "availability:InStoreOnly");
};
```

Comment: `find` is a jQuery function, `document` is a DOM element, not a jQuery object. Try `avail = $("div.badgeIds")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var avail = $("div.badgeIds");
var txt = $("div.badgeIds").text().trim();

 

if (txt == "Preorder") {
      avail.attr("itemprop", "availability:Preorder");
} else if (txt == "Online Only") {
      avail.attr("itemprop", "availability:OnlineOnly");
} else if (txt == "Available In Store Only") {
      avail.attr("itemprop", "availability:InStoreOnly");
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 

<div class="badgeIds" itemtype="https://schema.org/ItemAvailability" itemprop="availability">
   Online Only
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed.

The other suggestions were great, but due to a weird quirk of our engine (not sure if the actual engine or if it's the db) I essentially have to write JS using JQuery methods like .attr(), etc.

However, this example allowed me to format in a way that the engine can pull it from the db and apply it to the code.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just

```
avail.attr("itemprop", "availability:" + avail.html().replace(/\s|Available/g, "");
```

And as @Barmer has commented

```
var avail = $("div.badgeIds");
```

Comment: No need to use `.trim()` if you're removing all spaces with `.replace()`.

Comment: Yap. Thanks @Barmar

Answer (score 0):

If there's more than one DOM element with this class, you need to use a loop. You can use `.each()` to loop over all the elements, or make use of the fact that `.attr()` can be given a function as the value argument and it will loop automatically. The function is called with `this` equal to the DOM element, and its return value is used as the new attribute.

```
$("div.badgeIds").attr("itemprop", function() {
    var html = $(this).html().trim();
    switch (html) {
        case "Preorder":
            return "availability:Preorder";
            break;
        case "Online Only":
            return "availability:OnlineOnly";
            break;
        case "Available In Store Only":
            return "availability:InStoreOnly";
            break;
        default:
            return "";
    }
});
```

BTW, you shouldn't make up your own attributes like this. If you need application-specific attributes, use the standard `data-XXX` attributes. So instead of `itemprop`, it should be `data-itemprop`. And in jQuery, you can make use of `.data()` for this (and it will automatically loop in the same way).

You can't use `document.find(selector)`. It needs to be `$(document).find(selector)`, because `find()` is a jQuery method, not a DOM method. But that's more simply written as just `$(selector)`

Answer (score 0):

Try `$("div.badgeId");`

Some code improvements as my points.

```js
var avail = $("#badgeId");
var text = avail.html().trim();
if (text  == "Preorder") {
      avail.attr("itemprop", "availability:Preorder");
} else if (text  == "Online Only") {
      avail.attr("itemprop", "availability:OnlineOnly");
} else if (text  == "Available In Store Only") {
      avail.attr("itemprop", "availability:InStoreOnly");
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="badgeId" class="badgeIds" data-itemtype="https://schema.org/ItemAvailability" data-itemprop="availability">
   Online Only
</div>
```